# On deleting the Row of GridView not working properly

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

Whenever I delete a row from the gridview which I select to delete, the row above to the selected row gets deleted. Dont know why. Please see my code for deleting.

```
  <asp:GridView ID="grdPostData" runat="server" Width="100%" border="1" Style="border: 1px solid #E5E5E5;" CellPadding="3" AutoGenerateColumns="False" AllowPaging="true" PageSize="10" CssClass="hoverTable" OnPageIndexChanging="grdPostData_PageIndexChanging" OnRowDataBound="grdPostData_RowDataBound" OnRowDeleting="grdPostData_RowDeleting" DataKeyNames="Id">
                <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="#CCCCCC" />
                <Columns>
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="title" HeaderText="Title" ItemStyle-Width="30" ControlStyle-CssClass="k-grid td" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="description" HeaderText="Description" ItemStyle-Width="30" ControlStyle-CssClass="k-grid td" />
                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Post Category" ItemStyle-Width="50">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlPostCategory" AppendDataBoundItems="true" runat="server"
                                AutoPostBack="false">
                                <%-- <asp:ListItem Text="Select" Value="0"></asp:ListItem>--%>
                            </asp:DropDownList>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="active" HeaderText="Active" ItemStyle-Width="30" ControlStyle-CssClass="k-grid td" />
                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Action" HeaderStyle-Width="15%">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:ImageButton ID="btnDelete" AlternateText="Delete" ImageUrl="~/images/delete.png" runat="server" Width="15" Height="15" CommandName="Delete" CausesValidation="false" OnClientClick="return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this record?')" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("Id") %>' />
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                    <asp:CommandField ButtonType="Image" ItemStyle-Width="15" EditImageUrl="~/images/edit.png" ShowEditButton="True" ControlStyle-Width="15" ControlStyle-Height="15" CancelImageUrl="~/images/close.png" UpdateImageUrl="~/images/update.png">
                        <ControlStyle Height="20px" Width="20px"></ControlStyle>
                    </asp:CommandField>
                </Columns>
            </asp:GridView>
```

Code behind for your ref:-

```
protected void grdPostData_RowDeleting(object sender, GridViewDeleteEventArgs e)
    {
        bool IsDeleted = false;

        int Id = Convert.ToInt32(grdPostData.DataKeys[e.RowIndex].Value.ToString());
        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DefaultCSRConnection"].ConnectionString))
        {
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand())
            {
                cmd.CommandText = "DELETE FROM tbl_Post WHERE Id=@Id";
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Id", Id);
                cmd.Connection = conn;
                conn.Open();
                IsDeleted = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery() > 0;
                conn.Close();
            }
        }
        if (IsDeleted)
        {
            ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "alert", "alert('Page Succesfully deleted');window.location ='csrposts.aspx';", true);
            grdPostData.DataBind();
        }
        else
        {
            Response.Write("Some error");
        }
    }
```

Please let me know where I am going wrong. I tried debugging the code and the Id was taking `0`.

Gridview bindinf Code:-

```
  public void BindGrid()
    {
        string strQuery = "Select Id, title, description, Active from tbl_Post Order by ID desc";
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(strQuery);
        DataTable dt = GetData(cmd);
        grdPostData.DataSource = dt;
        grdPostData.DataBind();
    }
    private DataTable GetData(SqlCommand cmd)
    {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DefaultCSRConnection"].ConnectionString);
        SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter();
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        cmd.Connection = conn;
        try
        {
            conn.Open();
            sda.SelectCommand = cmd;
            sda.Fill(dt);
            return dt;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
        finally
        {
            conn.Close();
            sda.Dispose();
            conn.Dispose();
        }
    }
```

Comment: did you check the ID is coming correct while debugging in `RowDeleting` event?

Comment: yes, I checked the ID is coming 0.

Comment: yes so it clearly indicates the id is wrong try this `int Id = Convert.ToInt32(grdPostData.DataKeys[e.RowIndex]["Id"])`

Comment: No,Still it is not deleting the one which I selected.

Comment: check the Id value this time.

Comment: still the ID values is 0.

Comment: hmm does the data you bind to grid contains the Id column?

Comment: No,As my Id column is set to Identity and it generates the Id when the Row is added

Comment: @RahulSutar - You want to delete row with `id` 0 only?

Comment: @RahulSingh: Yes, As all other column sometime can be same.

Comment: Have you bind complete table to gridview?

Comment: @ALOK: Yes I have binded the table to gridview and it is working properly

Comment: do you mind to use RowCommand ?

Comment: @NiMa: If it works as per my requirement, I wont Mind. :)

Comment: @RahulSutar so please take a look at this link : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26861489/call-function-behind-the-image-button-in-gridview/26861845#26861845

Comment: @Nima: Ok let me try and will let you know

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Updated Solution. Completely Working. I am Creating those textboxes in DataBound and theirs a if condition that checks whether Gridview is Empty or Not. 
  If Gridview is empty then HeaderRow wont be created so that Gridview and Page is able to display else HeaderRow will be Displayed.
  Hope this Works for You.

aspx:-

```
  <%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Master.Master" AutoEventWireup="true"
CodeFile="csrposts.aspx.cs" Inherits="CSRProject.csrposts" %>
  <asp:GridView ID="grdPostData" runat="server" Width="100%" border="1" Style="border: 1px solid #E5E5E5;"
                CellPadding="3" AutoGenerateColumns="False" AllowPaging="true" PageSize="4" CssClass="hoverTable"
                OnPageIndexChanging="grdPostData_PageIndexChanging" OnDataBound="grdPostPageData_DataBound"
                OnRowDataBound="grdPostData_RowDataBound" DataKeyNames="Id" OnRowDeleting="grdPostData_RowDeleting"
                OnRowEditing="grdPostData_RowEditing" OnRowUpdating="grdPostData_RowUpdating"
                OnRowCancelingEdit="grdPostData_RowCancelingEdit">
                <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="#CCCCCC" />
                <Columns>
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="title" HeaderText="Title" ItemStyle-Width="30" ControlStyle-CssClass="k-grid td" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="description" HeaderText="Description" ItemStyle-Width="30"
                        ControlStyle-CssClass="k-grid td" />
                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Post Category" ItemStyle-Width="50">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlPostCategory" AppendDataBoundItems="true" runat="server"
                                AutoPostBack="false">
                                <%-- <asp:ListItem Text="Select" Value="0"></asp:ListItem>--%>
                            </asp:DropDownList>
                            <asp:Label ID="lblId" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Id") %>'> </asp:Label>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="active" HeaderText="Active" ItemStyle-Width="30" ControlStyle-CssClass="k-grid td" />
                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Action" HeaderStyle-Width="15%">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:LinkButton ID="lbltbDelete" runat="server" OnClick="lbltbDelete_Click" Text="Delete"
                                OnClientClick="return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this record?')"
                                CausesValidation="false" />
                            <asp:ImageButton ID="btnDelete" AlternateText="Delete" CommandName="Delete" ImageUrl="~/images/delete.png"
                                runat="server" Width="15" Height="15" CausesValidation="false" OnClientClick="return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this record?')" />
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                    <asp:CommandField ButtonType="Image" ItemStyle-Width="15" EditImageUrl="~/images/edit.png"
                        ShowEditButton="True" ControlStyle-Width="15" ControlStyle-Height="15" CancelImageUrl="~/images/close.png"
                        UpdateImageUrl="~/images/update.png">
                        <ControlStyle Height="20px" Width="20px"></ControlStyle>
                    </asp:CommandField>
                </Columns>
                <EmptyDataTemplate>
                    No Result Found
                </EmptyDataTemplate>
            </asp:GridView>
```

Aspx.cs

```
   protected void grdPostPageData_DataBound(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        GridViewRow row = new GridViewRow(0, 0, DataControlRowType.Header, DataControlRowState.Normal);
        for (int i = 0; i < grdPostData.Columns.Count; i++)
        {
            TableHeaderCell cell = new TableHeaderCell();
            TextBox txtSearch = new TextBox();
            txtSearch.Attributes["placeholder"] = grdPostData.Columns[i].HeaderText;
            txtSearch.CssClass = "form-control HaydaBre";
            cell.Controls.Add(txtSearch);
            row.Controls.Add(cell);
        }
        if (grdPostData.Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            grdPostData.HeaderRow.Parent.Controls.AddAt(0, row);
        }
        else
        {

        }
    }

    protected void grdPostData_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        /*
        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.Header)
        {

            GridViewRow row = new GridViewRow(0, 0, DataControlRowType.Header, DataControlRowState.Normal);
            for (int i = 0; i < grdPostData.Columns.Count; i++)
            {
                TableHeaderCell cell = new TableHeaderCell();
                TextBox txtSearch = new TextBox();
                txtSearch.Attributes["placeholder"] = grdPostData.Columns[i].HeaderText;
                txtSearch.CssClass = "form-control HaydaBre";
                cell.Controls.Add(txtSearch);
                row.Controls.Add(cell);
            }
             grdPostData.HeaderRow.Parent.Controls.AddAt(-1, row);
           // e.Row.Parent.Controls.AddAt(1, row);
        }
        */
        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
            SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DefaultCSRConnection"].ConnectionString);
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from tbl_PostCategory ", conn);
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter();
            da.SelectCommand = cmd;
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            da.Fill(dt);

            if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                DropDownList DropDownList1 =
                (DropDownList)e.Row.FindControl("ddlPostCategory");
                DropDownList1.DataSource = dt;
                DropDownList1.DataTextField = "cat_title";
                DropDownList1.DataValueField = "cat_title";
                DropDownList1.DataBind();
            }
        }
    }
```

Row Deleting Code is Same.

Comment: yes it is working, now I want to remove the label which is giving message in the footer and I want imageButton in place of link button

Comment: Thanks alok, I modified according to me and finally it worked..:)

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks good. Hope its not a problem from database. Try this
Add this to Gridview

```
   OnRowCommand="GridView_RowCommand"
```

CodeBehing:-

```
   protected void GridView_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
   {
     if(e.CommandName=="Delete") 
     {
      // Get the value of command argument
      int Id= convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument);
      // Do whatever operation you want.  
     }
   }
```

Alternatively:-
Add onclick event on your imagebutton of delete and try this

```
   protected void ImageButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {

         ImageButton btn = sender as ImageButton;
         GridViewRow gRow = (GridViewRow)btn.NamingContainer;
         int id =Convert.ToInt32((gRow.FindControl("lblId") as Label).Text);

   }
```

Update:-
  Change your itemtemplate to this

```
   <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Post Category" ItemStyle-Width="50">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlPostCategory" AppendDataBoundItems="true" runat="server"
                            AutoPostBack="false">
                            <%-- <asp:ListItem Text="Select" Value="0"></asp:ListItem>--%>
                        </asp:DropDownList>
                        <asp:Label ID="lblId" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Id") %>' </asp:Label>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
```

So Fetched Id will be visible next to dropdownlist. Make sure its displaying correct value

Comment: I am not getting `e.CommandName` in my ` protected void grdPostData_RowDeleting(object sender, GridViewDeleteEventArgs e)`

Comment: Ok my bad. it works only in RowCommand Event. I think you dont require CommandArgument, so try removing it else please share your Gridview Bind Code.

Comment: Ok, let me remove and try

Comment: Where are you calling this BindGrid() method?

Comment: on Page_Load under `if (!IsPostBack) {BindGrid()}`

Comment: take a label in any itemtemplate in gridview and display it using eval("ID"). This will show what Id you are getting.

Comment: can you explain in writing code? please it will be clear

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/65893/discussion-between-rahul-sutar-and-alok).