# ASP.NET Gridview Delete Command Event

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, buttonfield

Hi I have created a buttonfield in my Gridview with the CommandName sent to Delete. I have also Set the  RowDeleting event on my GridView to a method. It doesnt run this method though. Giving me the error " Deleting is not supported by data source 'Cars' unless DeleteCommand is specified. "

My question is how do I get a button to launch an event similar to the GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged with the Select command. Thanks

Comment: Could you post any code you have so far?

Comment: you should read about RowCommand event gridview

Comment: we'd be no better than a blind men until you provide your piece of code :)

Comment: take a look at this Q&A ,hope it helps : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26861489/call-function-behind-the-image-button-in-gridview/26861845#26861845

Answer (score 0):

Have you declared your DataSource like this?

`<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" DeleteCommand="YourDeleteCommand">
        <DeleteParameters />
    </asp:SqlDataSource>`

This will let the GridView know how to perform the delete operation...

Answer (score 0):

The problem was I didn't create the row deleted event as well as the row delete event.